# There was an error while loading the package SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016

I have created one SSIS package for data flow and its perfectly working fine for me (with my credentials). However, when its opened by another person with another login ID (credentials) its showing error:

Please see the below screenshot.Looks like its an access error. How can I give access so that anyone can open it.

The error I'm getting is :

> the operation failed because the databse manager failed to access either the databse manager configuration file or the database configuration file.
>   There ware errors while loading the package. See the error list for details.
>   Error loading Package.dtsx. Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified satte. You may not be 
>   authorized to access this information. This occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.

Upon searching on net. I think I can set "DontSaveSensitive". However,unable to find out how to do this? Whats are the steps I need to follow? 
Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/access-control-for-sensitive-data-in-packages

[image: Package loading failed]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Kudos for pinpointing issue. To solve it:

Open project solution from working credentials.

1. Right click on project.
2. Go to properties
3. Change the security level to `DontSaveSensitive`.

[image: img]

I've answered your question about `unable to find out how to do this`
Hope this works. Else come back here and we might suggest different approach.